# JQuery Calender selection not working when selected date is falling over combobox

Tags: jquery, combobox, calendar

When I am selecting a date from JQuery Calendar and the selection date if falls on a Combobox then it is not working. It is selecting the combobox value not the calendar selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem in the Z-Index of the Drop box which was floating over the Calendar Pop Up and making the selection of calendar to the Drop Box.

```
   So I just modified the CSS of the Combo Box which was not working as it was inheriting the CSS of the JQuery Combo box Style with important.
```

Like below :

```
      .DropCSS{
                font-size: 1em;
                z-index: 10 !important;
```

}

It worked for me like Wow.......... !!!

Thank you very much all for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Check this,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(function () {          
            $("#date").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showOn: "button"
            });          
        });
```